# sequalize join in where clause to relate two tables

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, join, sequelize.js

I have two table t1 and t2 related as one to many, t1 has id primary key and t2 has id as foreign key

How can I query in sequalize to find records from t2 which have t1.id ='value'  using joins

it should give res as following sql query gives

```
SELECT[t2].[id], [t2].[c1], [t2].[c2], [t2].[c3], [t2].[c4], [t1].[id] AS[t1.id], [t1].[cID] AS[t1.cID] FROM[t2] AS[t2] INNER JOIN[t1] AS[t1] ON[t2].[id] = [t1].[id] AND[t1].[cID] = 'value' WHERE[t2].[sF] = 'value';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st we have to associate the two table t1 and t2,
as par given info in question this association should as

> t1.hasMany(t2, { foreignKey: 'id' });
>
> t2.belongsTo(t1, { foreignKey: 'id' })

then

```
t2.findAll(
  {
  attributes: ['id','c1','c2','c3','c4'
  ],
  required: true,
  where: {
    sF: 'value',
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: t1,
      attributes: ['cID'],
      required: true,
      where: {
        cID:'value',
      }
    }
  ]
}  ).then((result)=>{console.log(result)})
```

assuming t1 and t2 are model declared in sequalize